# We need to stop search engine bots visits on some specific pages

Tags: plugins

We’ve created some pages on our wordpress site and we need to stop search engine bots visits on those specific pages.

I’ve recorded a video on this issue,

https://www.loom.com/share/6f1d8f9bc30f453abd9f5b930a6fe351

is there any plugin available to do that or if u know any way how to do that automatically?

Letme know your opinion, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not WordPress related, it is more a SEO stuff. I'm not an SEO expert, but anyways, apparently, you are doing the indexing steps correctly.

- Effectively, those posts have the meta tag `<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow"/>`
- Your sitemap `https://modelhomemakeover.ca/post-sitemap.xml` apparently is not showing those posts. Additionally, you have to upload the sitemap to Google Search Console.
- If you search in google `site:https://modelhomemakeover.ca/`, at least in my case, those posts are not showing in the 279 results.

In summary, you are doing the correct steps, BUT, keep in mind that the parameter `noindex`, anyways, can be avoided for the crawlers.

This is from Moz.com:

> It is important to note that malicious crawlers are likely to completely ignore meta directives and as such, this protocol does not make a good security mechanism. If you have private information that you don’t want to make publicly searchable, choose a more secure approach, such as password protection, to keep visitors from viewing confidential pages.

Additionally, you can add the directives into a robots.txt. You can read further [here](https://moz.com/learn/seo/robots-meta-directive).

Probably, you are receiving some malicious or not user traffic (apparently not a Google crawler). Maybe, you can use a plugin like **Wordfence**, in order to get further information.